# How do you surprise Moon Jellies?

Tags: splash

I'm stuck on a mission in Runaway's (aka Dena's) "Splash" Android game.

The mission is: "Jelly Surprise" and says "Surprise a school of 5 Moon Jellies".

I can't seem to figure out what to do to complete it.

- I created 5 Lipped Moon JellyFish
- I put them into a school (they all move together when school leader is moved)
- I try to surprise them with another fish of various species and they disperse; but it never seems to progress the mission (the mission counter says 0 out of 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the quest you have to surprise all 5 jellyfish at once. The best way to do this is to create a school of 10 or so Lipped Moon Jellyfish, then surprise that school and there is a better chance that you will surprise at least 5 jellyfish at once.

Comment: LOL! I accidentally did **just that** yesterday (created a 10-size school for another mission and succeeded in this one). +1 and accept

Answer (score 1):

You can also scare a school of five with a school of three other bigger fish.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that all you have to do is move the fish around to all 5 of the moon jellies and get all 5 of their eyes to close.
Each time you get all 5 of their eyes to close that counts as 1 time.